# Error index is not defined

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

I'm new to angularjs and i'm struggling with something.
I have a code that orders blocks (called themes) depending on when you click UP or Down buttons. But i'm getting the error saying that "index is not defined". Yet, I believe i've defined it. If not, where should I declare it ?

Thanks in advance.

Angular/Coffeescript code

```
move = (origin, destination) ->
console.log(index)
    temp = $scope.themes[destination]
    $scope.themes[destination] = $scope.themes[origin]
    $scope.themes[origin] = temp

  $scope.moveUp = (index) ->
    console.log(index)
    $scope.themes.move(index)

  $scope.moveDown = (index) ->
    console.log(index)
    move(index)
```

HTML/Jade code

```
md-icon.moveUp(
      md-menu-origin
      md-svg-icon='arrow_upward'
      ng-if="$ctrl.isAdmin"
      ng-show="hover"
      ng-disabled="$last"
      ng-click="moveUp($index)"
    )
    md-icon.moveDown(
      md-menu-origin
      md-svg-icon='arrow_downward'
      ng-if="$ctrl.isAdmin"
      ng-show="hover"
      ng-click="moveDown($index)"
    )
```

Comment: move = (origin, destination) ->
console.log(index)
The console.log never finds the index.

Comment: `$index` is defined when used inside ng-repeat.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You helped me finding out the issue. Cheers.